# R mutate error while merging every two rows into one

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `CSV` data in which I want to merge every `two rows` in each of the columns. The code below works fine on other `CSVs`. However, it returns an `error` while `mutating` with this particular dataset.

How can I fix this?
The purpose is to merge every two rows in each of the columns in this dataset.

Error:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `id = rep(1:(n()/2), each = 2)`.
x `id` must be size 179 or 1, not 178.

Code:

```
df = df%>% mutate(id = rep(1:(n()/2), each = 2)) %>% 
           group_by(id) %>% 
           summarize(across(date_received:permit,
          ~trimws(paste0(.x, collapse = " "))))
```

Data:

```
structure(list(date_received = c("Existing/Pool", "1/26/2021", 
"Existing ", "2/3/2021", "Existing", "2/10/2021", "Abandonment", 
"2/11/2021", "Holding Tank", "2/11/2021", "Existing/Additon", 
"2/19/2021", "Abandonment", "2/23/2021", "Existing ", "3/2/2021", 
"Existing", "3/2/2021", "Existing", "3/2/2021", "Existing/Pool", 
"3/3/2021", "Abandonment", "2/11/2021", "Abandonment", "3/8/2021", 
"Existing", "3/10/2021", "Abandonment", "3/10/2021", "Abandonment", 
"3/11/2021", "Abandonment", "3/25/2021", "Abandonment", "3/30/2021", 
"Abandonment", "4/6/2021", "Abandonment", "4/2/2021", "Abandonment", 
"4/7/2021", "Abandonment", "4/16/2021", "Holding Tank", "4/19/2021", 
"Existing/Pool", "4/21/2021", "Holding Tank", "4/26/2021", "Abandonment", 
"4/27/2021", "Existing Addition", "4/1/2020", "Portables", "4/30/2021", 
"Existing ", "5/17/2021", "Existing", "5/27/2021", "Existing", 
"5/27/2021", "Abandonment ", "6/2/2021", "Existing", "6/4/2021", 
"Abandonment", "6/9/2021", "Portables", "6/14/2021", "Pool Addition", 
"6/28/2021", "Existing Addition", "6/28/20201", "Abandonment", 
"6/29/2021", "Holding Tank", "6/21/2021", "Abandonment", "7/2/2021", 
"Pool Addition", "7/6/2021", "Holding Tank", "7/9/2021", "Abandonment", 
"7/15/2021", "Abandonment", "7/16/2021", "Holding Tank", "7/27/2021", 
"Abandonment", "7/28/2021", "Holding Tank", "7/28/2021", "Existing", 
"8/3/2021", "Abandonment", "8/3/2021", "Existing", "8/17/2021", 
"Abandonment", "9/8/2021", "Abandonment", "9/14/2021", "Existing", 
"8/19/2021", "Existing ", "9/20/2021", "Restroom", "9/20/2021", 
"Holding Tank", "9/22/2021", "Existing", "10/7/2021", "Holding Tank", 
"10/5/2021", "Existing", "10/8/2021", "Existing", "10/13/2021", 
"Holding Tank", "10/15/2021", "Abandonment", "10/18/2021", "Abandonment", 
"10/19/2021", "Holding Tank", "10/22/2021", "Abandonment", "10/25/2021", 
"Holding Tank", "10/25/2021", "Restroom", "10/27/2021", "Abandonment", 
"11/1/2021", "Restroom", "11/4/2021", "Abandonment", "11/4/2021", 
"Existing", "6/14/2021", "Existing", "11/9/2021", "Holding Tank", 
"11/10/2021", "Abandonment", "11/18/2021", "Abandonment", "11/18/2021", 
"Abandonment", "11/18/2021", "Abandonment", "11/18/2021", "Existing", 
"11/22/2021", "Abandonment ", "11/30/2021", "Abandonment ", "Abandonment ", 
"11/30/2021", "Abandonment ", "11/30/2021", "Abandonment ", "11/30/2021", 
"Abandonment ", "11/30/2021", "Abandonment ", "11/30/2021", "Abandonment ", 
"11/17/2021", "Abandonment", "12/3/2021", "Abandonment", "12/3/2021", 
"Abandonment", "12/13/2021", "Abandonment", "12/14/2021"), date_approved = c("HC", 
"1/27/2021", "CE", "2/3/2021", "NC", "2/10/2021", "VV", "2/11/2021", 
"SB", "2/18/2021", "VV", "2/19/2021", "HC", "2/23/2021", "CE", 
"3/2/2021", "NC", "3/2/2021", "NC", "3/2/2021", "HC", "3/3/2021", 
"", "2/19/2021", "", "3/8/2021", "NC", "3/10/2021", "NC", "3/10/2021", 
"HC", "3/11/2021", "HC", "3/25/2021", "NC", "3/30/2021", "SB", 
"4/6/2021", "NC", "4/2/2021", "NC", "4/7/2021", "HC", "4/19/2021", 
"NC", "4/20/2021", "VV", "4/21/2021", "VV", "4/26/2021", "NC", 
"4/27/2021", "SB", "4/28/2021", "CE", "5/3/2021", "", "5/17/2021", 
"VV", "5/27/2021", "VV", "5/27/2021", "", "6/3/2021", "", "6/4/2021", 
"", "6/9/2021", "NC", "6/14/2021", "SB", "6/28/2021", "", "6/28/2021", 
"", "6/29/2021", "", "7/1/2021", "VV", "7/6/2021", "SB", "7/6/2021", 
"VV", "7/9/2021", "SB", "7/15/2021", "HC", "7/16/2021", "NC", 
"7/27/2021", "HC", "7/28/2021", "HC", "7/28/2021", "", "8/3/2021", 
"", "8/4/2021", "", "8/17/2021", "SB", "9/8/2021", "NC", "9/14/2021", 
"", "9/14/2021", "NC", "9/20/2021", "CE", "9/20/2021", "NC", 
"9/22/2021", "", "10/7/2021", "", "10/7/2021", "", "10/8/2021", 
"SB", "10/13/2021", "", "10/15/2021", "", "10/19/2021", "HC", 
"10/19/2021", "HC", "10/22/2021", "", "10/25/2021", "", "10/25/2021", 
"", "10/28/2021", "", "11/1/2021", "", "11/4/2021", "", "11/5/2021", 
"", "11/9/2021", "", "11/9/2021", "", "", "", "11/18/2021", "", 
"11/18/2021", "", "11/18/2021", "", "11/18/2021", "", "11/22/2021", 
"", "11/30/2021", "", "", "11/30/2021", "", "11/30/2021", "", 
"11/30/2021", "", "11/30/2021", "", "11/30/2021", "", "11/17/2021", 
"", "12/3/2021", "", "12/3/2021", "", "12/3/2021", "", "12/15/2021"
), ap = c("", "AP-21-001", "", "AP-21-002", "", "AP-21-003", 
"", "AP-21-004", "", "AP-21-005", "", "AP-21-006", "", "AP-21-007", 
"", "AP-21-008", "", "AP-21-009", "", "AP-21-010", "", "AP-21-011", 
"", "AP-21-012", "", "AP-21-013", "", "AP-21-014", "", "AP-21-015", 
"", "AP-21-016", "", "AP-21-017", "", "AP-21-018", "", "AP-21-019", 
"", "AP-21-020", "", "AP-21-021", "", "AP-21-022", "", "AP-21-023", 
"", "AP-21-024", "", "AP-21-025", "", "AP-21-026", "", "AP-21-027", 
"", "AP-21-028", "", "AP-21-029", "", "AP-21-030", "", "AP-21-031", 
"", "AP-21-032", "", "AP-21-033", "", "AP-21-034", "", "AP-21-034", 
"", "AP-21-035", "", "AP-21-036", "", "AP-21-037", "", "AP-21-038", 
"", "AP-21-039", "", "AP-21-040", "", "AP-21-041", "", "AP-21-042", 
"", "AP-21-043", "", "AP-21-044", "", "AP-21-045", "", "AP-21-046", 
"", "AP-21-047", "", "AP-21-048", "", "AP-21-049", "", "AP-21-050", 
"", "AP-21-051", "", "AP-21-052", "", "AP-21-053", "", "AP-21-054", 
"", "AP-21-055", "", "AP-21-056", "", "AP-21-057", "", "AP-21-058", 
"", "AP-21-059", "", "AP-21-060", "", "AP-21-061", "", "AP-21-062", 
"", "AP-21-063", "", "AP-21-064", "", "AP-21-065", "", "AP-21-066", 
"", "AP-21-067", "", "AP-21-068", "", "AP-21-069", "", "AP-21-070", 
"", "AP-21-071", "", "AP-21-072", "", "AP-21-073", "", "AP-21-074", 
"", "AP-21-075", "", "AP-21-076", "", "AP-21-077", "", "AP-21-078", 
"", "", "AP-21-080", "", "AP-21-081", "", "AP-21-082", "", "AP-21-083", 
"", "AP-21-084", "", "AP-21-085", "", "AP-21-086", "", "AP-21-087", 
"", "AP-21-088", "", "AP-21-089"), permit = c("", "06-SE-2224986", 
"", "06-SE-2227597", "", "06-SM-2239687", "", "06-", "", "06-SM-2241767", 
"", "06-SE-2243142", "", "06-SE-2244287", "", "06-SE-2246427", 
"", "06-SM-2246414", "", "06-SM-2246400", "", "06-SE-2247078", 
"", "06-SM-2242491", "", "06-SM-2248390", "", "06-SM-2249588", 
"", "06-SM-2249687", "", "06-SE-2250115", "", "06-SE-2254824", 
"", "06-SM-2255976", "", "06-SM-2269208", "", "06-SM-2267853", 
"", "06-SM-2269667", "", "06-SM-2273781", "", "06-SM-2273781", 
"", "06-SE-2274109", "", "06-SE-2275335", "", "06-SM-2276119", 
"", "06-SM-2045833", "", "06-SE-2278410", "", "06-SM-2292821", 
"", "06-SE-2296438", "", "06-SE-", "", "06-SM-2308253", "", "06-SE-2308815", 
"", "06-SM-2310625", "", "06-SM-2310987", "", "06-SM-2316223", 
"", "", "", "06-SE-2316719", "", "06-SM-2327886", "", "06-SE-2328314", 
"", "06-SM-2328437", "", "06-SE-2329714", "", "06-SM-2331651", 
"", "06-SE-2332160", "", "06-SM-2335477", "", "06-SE-2335855", 
"", "06-SE-2335957", "", "06-SE-2337766", "", "06-SE-2338114", 
"", "06-SE-2351769", "", "06-SM-2368036", "", "06-SM-2369869", 
"", "06-SE-23651769", "", "06-SM-2371532", "", "06-SE-2371710", 
"", "06-SM-237238", "", "06-SM-2407385", "", "06-SM-2407543", 
"", "06-SM-2407855", "", "06-SM-2409931", "", "06-SE-2410182", 
"", "06-SE-2411071", "", "06-SE-2411268", "", "06-SE-2412725", 
"", "06-SE-2413035", "", "06-SE-2413090", "", "06-SE-2413883", 
"", "06-SM-2415394", "", "06-SE-2416802", "", "06-SE-2417359", 
"", "06-SM-2408057", "", "06-SM-2418381", "", "06-SE-2418776", 
"", "06-SM-2421477", "", "06-SM-2421473", "", "06-SM-", "", "06-SM-", 
"", "06-SM-2410994", "Pool", "AP1766846", "Classroom E", "Classroom F", 
"AP1766856", "Classroom C", "AP1766858", "Classroom A", "AP1766862", 
"Landscape Area", "AP1766864", "Classroom B", "AO1766867", "", 
"06-SE-2420566", "", "06-E-2425187", "", "", "", "06-SM-2424110", 
"", "06-SE-2428789")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-179L))
```

Comment: The error message implies you have an odd number of rows. You can't merge every two rows in that case. Do you want to ignore the last row/first row/some other row? What's the rule for merging when you have an odd number?

Comment: Try `group_by(id = gl(n(), 2, n()))`

Comment: Try `group_by(id = (1:n()+1) %/% 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the 'id', you can increase the count of rows by 1, replicate each number by twice and then select the first `n`.

```
df%>% mutate(id = rep(1:((n()+1)/2), each = 2)[1:n()]) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(across(date_received:permit,
                   ~trimws(paste0(.x, collapse = " "))))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 90 x 5
      id date_received              date_approved ap        permit       
   <int> <chr>                      <chr>         <chr>     <chr>        
 1     1 Existing/Pool 1/26/2021    HC 1/27/2021  AP-21-001 06-SE-2224986
 2     2 Existing  2/3/2021         CE 2/3/2021   AP-21-002 06-SE-2227597
 3     3 Existing 2/10/2021         NC 2/10/2021  AP-21-003 06-SM-2239687
 4     4 Abandonment 2/11/2021      VV 2/11/2021  AP-21-004 06-          
 5     5 Holding Tank 2/11/2021     SB 2/18/2021  AP-21-005 06-SM-2241767
 6     6 Existing/Additon 2/19/2021 VV 2/19/2021  AP-21-006 06-SE-2243142
 7     7 Abandonment 2/23/2021      HC 2/23/2021  AP-21-007 06-SE-2244287
 8     8 Existing  3/2/2021         CE 3/2/2021   AP-21-008 06-SE-2246427
 9     9 Existing 3/2/2021          NC 3/2/2021   AP-21-009 06-SM-2246414
10    10 Existing 3/2/2021          NC 3/2/2021   AP-21-010 06-SM-2246400
# ... with 80 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `group_by(id = (1:n()-1) %/% 2 + 1)`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id = (1:n()-1) %/% 2 + 1) %>%
  summarize(across(date_received:permit,
            ~ trimws(paste0(.x, collapse = " "))))

# # A tibble: 90 × 5
#       id date_received              date_approved ap        permit       
#    <dbl> <chr>                      <chr>         <chr>     <chr>        
#  1     1 Existing/Pool 1/26/2021    HC 1/27/2021  AP-21-001 06-SE-2224986
#  2     2 Existing  2/3/2021         CE 2/3/2021   AP-21-002 06-SE-2227597
#  3     3 Existing 2/10/2021         NC 2/10/2021  AP-21-003 06-SM-2239687
#  4     4 Abandonment 2/11/2021      VV 2/11/2021  AP-21-004 06-          
#  5     5 Holding Tank 2/11/2021     SB 2/18/2021  AP-21-005 06-SM-2241767
#  6     6 Existing/Additon 2/19/2021 VV 2/19/2021  AP-21-006 06-SE-2243142
#  7     7 Abandonment 2/23/2021      HC 2/23/2021  AP-21-007 06-SE-2244287
#  8     8 Existing  3/2/2021         CE 3/2/2021   AP-21-008 06-SE-2246427
#  9     9 Existing 3/2/2021          NC 3/2/2021   AP-21-009 06-SM-2246414
# 10    10 Existing 3/2/2021          NC 3/2/2021   AP-21-010 06-SM-2246400
# # … with 80 more rows
```

---

`%/%` indicates *integer division*. If `n()` is 15, the grouping variable will gives

```r
(1:15-1) %/% 2 + 1

# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8
```